# where is define autocomplete tag in ST3 ? I have duplicate "<" problem

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I use ST3, when I press "`<p`", autocomplete menu propose "`<p>`" tag, but the result is

```
<<p></p>
```

Where is stocked the default code of autocompletion? Why do I have a duplicate "`<`" char, and how fix do I it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use autoclose tag or press only `p` and autocomplete transforme to `<p></p>`